# "If two people say you are drunk, go to bed!"

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

In my mother tongue there is this funny saying that always made me laugh. It normally refers to situations that have nothing to do with getting drunk.

Imagine two friends trying to convince a third that something is the case or that this third friend did something although he does not remember it.

> A: You hated going on that trip with me last summer.
> B: Which trip? Are you dreaming? I did not go on any trip with you last summer!
> C: Come on, the 3D Youth camp?
> B: That was two years ago! 
> A: *That* was totally last summer! Man, you're losing it!
> B: You gotta be kidding me! ... What... Is this a prank?
> C: A, ***if two people say you are drunk, go to bed!***

So, A and C insist that the trip was last summer, whereas B believes it was two years ago. In my language, this expression means that if two persons state something as being true about you, you'd better take it into consideration, you might be wrong. Two witnesses against one.

Is there an English idiom or proverb that expresses this idea and could go in the last line of this dialogue?

Comment: There is always the instruction that Moses gave to the Israelites: “A single witness shall not rise up against a person regarding any wrongdoing or any sin [r]that he commits; on the [s]testimony of two or three witnesses a matter shall be confirmed" (Deuteronomy 19:15 NASB).

Comment: @rhetorician Yes, when I was searching for an equivalent, this reference crossed my mind... But I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to express this idea.

Comment: This is definitely not what you are looking for, but a follow-up thing person 'A' could call person 'C': Toad-eater— “In England, when someone is a false-flatterer, or pretends to agree with everything someone else says in order to win their favor, we call that ‘toad-eating.’”

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, you can yell out “majority rules!”, as stated by [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Majority%20Rules):

> In the same way, can also be used to prove or disprove facts (however ridiculous), in that if the majority agree that something is true/untrue then it is true/untrue - the 'rule' is thus useful for winning arguments where you know others will agree with you. Arguably pretty much just democracy distilled to the level of petty playground rivalry.

Comment: Yes, that does express the meaning. I wonder if there are any synonyms of this.